# Shortcode showing instead of "From Name" when sending SMS messages in MobileConnect

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

I have a "From name" configured for my shortcode for SMS messages in mobileconnect.
However, when sending SMS messages, a shortcode is displayed as the sender and not the "From Name", even though I have selected it in my SMS settings.

**Problem:**
**X** Recieving SMS message from "3680".

**Expected :**
**->** Recieving SMS message from "INFO".

Have you ever encountered this problem ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

**EDIT :** Apparently, the issue was on the mobile aggregator side. The support contacted them and now the issue is resolved. Thank you for your response. I hope this helps.

Comment: What country are you sending to?

Comment: I'm sending to France.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this KA "[MobileConnect Considerations for Sending to France](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317212&type=1&mode=1)"

> When using MobileConnect for SMS Messages or Campaigns, you will be given the opportunity apply a FromName to your Account or Message, when provisioning a French ShortCode to your account you will be asked whether to choose using a FromName or use the Short Code, you cannot have both and this is a configuration setting behind the scenes, but the Marketing Cloud will still suggest you have the option to choose.

So it appears this account is configured to send using short code, and when you use a fromname is randomly assigns in a different short code

Comment: Thank you for the Knowledge Article. I don't know if it applies 100%, because i have 2 shortcodes and only one of those doesn't show the From Name. The other one works fine when i choose a From Name.